# This function cannot read the file from relative path. How do I enable the function to read the file from relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

This is the function for open a file and read the file:

```py
def readFileBytes(
    filePath: Union[Path, str]
) -> bytes:
    if isinstance(filePath, str):
        filePath = Path(filePath)
    fileObject = open(filePath, 'rb')
    rawBytes = fileObject.read()
    fileObject.close()

    print("Path: ", filePath)
    return rawBytes
```

And the file path that I want to import is: 
`/Users/zzzz/Desktop/2023/AI/Project/FinalProject/minecraft/villages/common/iron.nbt`

And my path file path is : 
`/Users/zzzz/Desktop/2023/AI/Project/Final Project/minecraft/test_nbt.py`

Whether I use:

```
path = './villages/commom/animals/cat_black.nbt'
nbt = readFileBytes(path)
```

or

```
path = '../villages/common/well_bottom.nbt'  # I know it is wrong...
nbt = readFileBytes(path)
```

It always gives me an error:

```
    fileObject = open(filePath, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'villages/common/well_bottom.nbt'
```

But if I use `/Users/zzzz/Desktop/2023/AI/Project/Final Project/minecraft/villages/common/iron.nbt`, (absolute path) it works.

What is the best/easy way to fix it?

Comment: Make sure that the working directory is `/Users/zzzz/Desktop/2023/AI/Project/FinalProject/minecraft` when executing the code.

Comment: Relative paths are relative to the "current working directory" of the program, which is **not necessarily** where the script is.

Comment: You can add this to your program `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to see what the actual current directory is.